# How to render an object from SVG in UIWebview along JQuery code?

Tags: jquery, ios, objective-c, svg, uiwebview

I loaded SVG image into UIWebView and i want to rendering element from SVG image while on click event on the UIWebView. is it possible to do ? I have tired UITapGesture but it gives x and y point of UIWebView. but i want object from SVG image.

Comment: What does "But when i try to rendering object from UIWebView can't able to get the object" mean?

Answer (score 0):

This is what i understood from your question.
You want add click to an SVG element which should trigger some event in IOS

You can make use of something called URL Catching in IOS.On click of the svg element trigger a url and implement these method in your code

```
application:handleOpenURL: (used for earlier iOS 4.1) application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation: (used for later iOS 4.1)
```

so that you can catch the url which is being triggered and can perform the desired operation.